# xml python parsing get parent node name : minidom

Tags: python, xml

how do i know a parent node's name say i am at label = "shirt", how do i know that its parent is john_carter whose parent is "FG". Is it possible to know ( in minidom )

-90
        
        .
        .
        .

```
        <Object type="Layer" id="6" label="FG" expanded="True">
            <Properties>
                <Property id="blur" constant="True">
                    <Value>0</Value>
                </Property>
                .
                .
                .


                <Property id="objects" expanded="True" constant="True">
                    <Object type="Layer" id="7" label="john_carter">
                        <Properties>
                            <Property id="blur" constant="True">
                                <Value>0</Value>
                            </Property>
                            .
                            .
                            .


                            <Property id="objects" expanded="True" constant="True">
                                <Object type="Layer" id="8" label="shirt" selected="True">
                                    <Properties>
                                        <Property id="blur" constant="True">
                                            <Value>0</Value>
                                        </Property>
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                .
                .
                .


    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: When posting sample XML, it's helpful if it's valid XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
import xml.dom.minidom

def getParentObjectNode(node):
    while node.parentNode:
        node = node.parentNode
        if node.nodeName == "Object":
            return node

xml = xml.dom.minidom.parse("C:\\myxml.xml")
for shirtNode in xml.getElementsByTagName("Object"):
    if shirtNode.getAttribute("label") == "shirt":
        break

shirtParentObject = getParentObjectNode(shirtNode)
print(shirtParentObject.getAttribute("label"))
shirtParentParentObject = getParentObjectNode(shirtParentObject)
print(shirtParentParentObject.getAttribute("label"))
```

Comment: thank you. is it possible to find out child node. FG to john_carter to shirt. that is , FG's child is john_carter and john_carter's child is shirt

Comment: basically i need to go only 3 (where as there are more than 5 ) levels into objects. is there a way to know the different levels

Comment: wait a while...no body should reply to this..i see that a little addition to the above will help. will post soon