# xml parsing issues with python

Tags: python, xml, xmldom

I have a xml doc that I'm trying to parse data from it with Python 2.7. I need to get the main tag associated with the Ports value.  I can get the information from the port no problem.

```
</User>
  <Testing>
    <Alert/>
    <XML>
      <Ports value="2222"/>
    </XML>
  </Testing>
  <Client>
    <XIF>
      <Assigned>
        <Assigned name="Open123">
          <Connection>
            <Ports value="1111"/>
            <Validate value="true"/>
          </Connection>
```

Some code I wrote:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import sys
import os



xmldoc = minidom.parse('c:/document.xml')

itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Ports')
for z in itemlist:
     print (z.attributes['value'].value + '\n')
```

Comment: What do you mean by `main tag`?

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499534/xml-python-parsing-get-parent-node-name-minidom

Comment: I guess that's my question, how do I get the tags associated with ports. So that I can have a listing that states these ports are in this element I guess. Sorry if my wording is incorrect.  I'm still trying to figure xml out with Python.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Please clarify, what your expected outcome should be.

Comment: so it will look print like this:  2222 :User  and then next one will print out like this 1111:client

Comment: I guess I need to get the parent tag for the ports.

Comment: The parent element of the one `Ports` element is named `Connection`, the other one `XML`. It is still not clear what you are looking for, other than that you might be looking for the name of an ancestor element, but it is not clear which one you want.